# ASP.Net Core pop up based authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, basic-authentication

The task at hand is to port an old application from an Apache httpd web service written in C to ASP.Net Core.  The old Apache web service, and more importantly, all the clients are using the old basic authentication, aka the pop-up based.  As not to have to rewrite all the clients, this behavior needs to be duplicated in ASP.Net Core.  The question is now?

There is a NuGet package, idunno.Authentication.Basic, that talks about how to implement basic authentication, but it does not invoke the pop-up.  Does anyone know how to get the pop-up-based authentication?

Just to be 100% clear: **This does NOT run on the Internet, rather it runs on a customer's Intranet**. The level of security is not designed to be hardened to stop hardcore hackers, just the average person, so basic authentication over HTTP is fine for this project. The main issue is the timeline and not having to rework multiple clients written in mutltiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a request back to the client with the `WWW-Authenticate` header and the response code of the request has to be `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`.
When the user has filled out the dialog and presses OK you will receive the password in the HTTP Header in the next request. Here is a simple example using HttpListener to illustrate what is going on:

```
using (var listener = new HttpListener())
{
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:23456/");
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
        var response = context.Response;
        
        Console.WriteLine("----------Request");
        for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Headers.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Headers.GetKey(i) + ":" +context.Request.Headers.Get(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Test\"");
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        context.Response.Close();
    }
}
```

you could try to add a BaseController in ASP.NET and override some of the methods to handle this use case such as `OnActionExecuting`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    // TODO: Check header and send response to client
    // context.HttpContext.Response
}
```